# Multiple outcomes/scenarios

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, logic

I got a problem that I have already created a solution for, but I'm wondering if there's a better way of solving the problem. Basically I have to create a flag for certain scenarios under a partition of ID and date. My solution involved mapping for all the possible scenarios, then creating "case when" statements for all these scenarios with the specific outcome. Basically, I was the one that created the outcomes. I am wondering if there's another way, something around letting SQL create the outcomes instead of myself.

Thanks a lot!

Background:

```
+----+-----------+--------+-------+------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |   Month   | Status | Value | Flag | Scenario Number |                               Scenario Description                                |
+----+-----------+--------+-------+------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 1/01/2016 | First  |   123 | No   |               1 | First, second and blank exists. Do not flag                                       |
|  1 | 1/01/2016 | Second |   456 | No   |               1 | First, second and blank exists. Do not flag                                       |
|  1 | 1/01/2016 |        |   789 | No   |               1 | First, second and blank exists. Do not flag                                       |
|  1 | 1/02/2016 | Second |   123 | Yes  |               2 | First does not exist, two second but have different values. Flag these as Yes     |
|  1 | 1/02/2016 | Second |   456 | Yes  |               2 | First does not exist, two second but have different values. Flag these as Yes     |
|  1 | 1/02/2016 | Second |   123 | No   |               3 | First does not exist, two second have same values. Do not flag                    |
|  1 | 1/02/2016 | Second |   123 | No   |               3 | First does not exist, two second have same values. Do not flag                    |
|  1 | 1/03/2016 | Second |   123 | No   |               4 | Only one entry of Second exist. Do no flag                                        |
|  1 | 1/04/2016 |        |   123 | Yes  |               5 | Two blanks for the partition. Flag these as Yes                                   |
|  1 | 1/04/2016 |        |   123 | Yes  |               5 | Two blanks for the partition. Flag these as Yes                                   |
|  1 | 1/05/2016 |        |       | No   |               6 | Only one entry of blank exist. Do not flag these                                  |
|  1 | 1/06/2016 | First  |   123 | Yes  |               7 | First exist for the partition. Do not flag                                        |
|  1 | 1/06/2016 |        |   456 | Yes  |               7 | First exist for the partition. Do not flag                                        |
|  1 | 1/07/2016 | Second |   123 | Yes  |               8 | First does not exist and second and blank do not have the same value. Flag these. |
|  1 | 1/07/2016 |        |   456 | Yes  |               8 | First does not exist and second and blank do not have the same value. Flag these. |
|  1 | 1/07/2016 | Second |   123 | Yes  |               8 | First does not exist and second and blank have the same value. Flag these.        |
|  1 | 1/07/2016 |        |   123 | Yes  |               8 | First does not exist and second and blank have the same value. Flag these.        |
+----+-----------+--------+-------+------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Data:

```
+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------------+
| ID |   Month   | Value | Priority | Expected_Flag |
+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | 1/01/2016 | 96.01 |          | Yes           |
|  1 | 1/01/2016 | 96.01 |          | Yes           |
|  1 | 1/02/2016 | 65.2  | First    | No            |
|  1 | 1/02/2016 | 3.47  | Second   | No            |
|  1 | 1/02/2016 | 45.99 |          | No            |
| 11 | 1/01/2016 | 25    |          | No            |
| 11 | 1/02/2016 | 74.25 | Second   | No            |
| 11 | 1/02/2016 | 74.25 | Second   | No            |
| 11 | 1/02/2016 | 23.25 |          | No            |
| 24 | 1/01/2016 | 1.25  | First    | No            |
| 24 | 1/01/2016 | 1.365 |          | No            |
| 24 | 1/04/2016 | 1.365 | First    | No            |
| 24 | 1/04/2016 | 1.365 |          | No            |
| 24 | 1/05/2016 | 1.365 | First    | No            |
| 24 | 1/05/2016 | 1.365 | First    | No            |
| 24 | 1/06/2016 | 1.365 | Second   | No            |
| 24 | 1/06/2016 | 1.365 | Second   | No            |
| 24 | 1/07/2016 | 1.365 | Second   | Yes           |
| 24 | 1/07/2016 | 1.365 |          | Yes           |
| 24 | 1/08/2016 | 1.365 | First    | No            |
| 24 | 1/08/2016 | 1.365 |          | No            |
| 24 | 1/09/2016 | 1.365 | Second   | No            |
| 24 | 1/09/2016 | 1.365 |          | No            |
| 27 | 1/01/2016 | 0     | Second   | Yes           |
| 27 | 1/01/2016 | 0     | Second   | Yes           |
| 27 | 1/02/2016 | 45.25 | Second   | No            |
|  3 | 1/01/2016 | 96.01 | First    | No            |
|  3 | 1/01/2016 | 96.01 | First    | No            |
|  3 | 1/03/2016 | 96.01 | First    | No            |
|  3 | 1/03/2016 | 96.01 | First    | No            |
| 35 | 1/01/2016 |       |          | Yes           |
| 35 | 1/01/2016 |       |          | Yes           |
| 35 | 1/02/2016 |       | First    | No            |
| 35 | 1/02/2016 |       | Second   | No            |
| 35 | 1/02/2016 |       |          | No            |
| 35 | 1/02/2016 |       |          | No            |
| 35 | 1/03/2016 |       | Second   | Yes           |
| 35 | 1/03/2016 |       | Second   | Yes           |
| 35 | 1/04/2016 |       | Second   | No            |
| 35 | 1/04/2016 |       | Second   | No            |
+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Are you saying that you use CASE statements to  determine whether the flag should be yes or no?

Comment: Ok.  I would put all the possible outcomes in a lookup table, rather than using CASE statements.  Then look up the values in the table with your SELECT statement.  The reason is that ifI you have to change them, it's much easier to change the table than it is to change the SQL procedure.  But, if you're asking whether to have SQL apply some sort of algorithm to determine what gets flagged and what doesn't, you probably won't gain much over just putting the correct values in a table.  It's even harder to change that down the line, too.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea! I will give that a go

Comment: Good.  Hope it helps!